# Response.ClearContent() method not getting in Asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

```
        System.IO.StringWriter objStringWriter = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter objHtmlTextWriter = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(objStringWriter);
        gv.RenderControl(objHtmlTextWriter);



        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=DemoExcel.xls");
        Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";

        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.Output.Write(objStringWriter.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.Close();
```

giving error Response does not contain definition for ClearContent in 
Asp.net Core

Comment: How about `Response.Clear();` ?

Comment: It shows same problem, same code work in Asp.net MVC finely but not in Asp.net Core

Answer (score 6):

Found this answer online 
https://forums.asp.net/t/1567637.aspx?Response+Clear+vs+Response+ClearContent+Response+ClearHeaders+

```
Response.Clear();
Response.Headers[HeaderNames.ContentDisposition] = "attachment; filename=DemoExcel.xls";
Response.WriteAsync(objStringWriter.ToString()).Wait()
```

Hopefully it helps someone